# What scope am I in when writing code within a Struts2/Apache Tiles .jsp, and how can I access my current Struts2 Action?

Tags: tomcat, struts2, apache-tiles

So here I am, writing a JSP script which is called by a Apache Tiles which is called by a Struts2 action. Everything works fine, but I'm just curious about what scopes I have access to.

1. I (think I) understand that the following blocks are in the JSP's scope, in that I have access to the various [JSP implicit objects](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro7.html):

   ```
   <% stuff in here (and variations of this type of tag) %>

   ${ stuff in here }
   ```
2. And I know I can access the Struts2 Action with the various [Struts2 Tags](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/generic-tag-reference.html), but I only have "bean access":

   ```
   <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
   <s:property value="beanAccessorHere"/>
   ```
3. And then, I only know one way of accessing the actual Action context (I think), but only in a Struts2 "if" tag:

   ```
   <s:if test="%{variableInMyAction == null}">
   </s:if>
   ```

So, I was wondering if

1. There was a way to access the Action context like **#3**, but in a more flexible manner like in **#1**.
2. If I can use the %{} syntax like in **#3** but in any place other than in a Struts "if" tag.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe I've figured it out.

> There was a way to access the Action context like #3, but in a more flexible manner like in #1.

I can use `<s:property value="%{now_in_action_context}"/>` to access variables in my Action, and, in fact, can use the `%{}` syntax in many different Struts tags.

> If I can use the %{} syntax like in #3 but in any place other than in a Struts "if" tag.

(Answered above)

I can also do things like use `<s:set name="myVar" value="%{somethingFromAction()}"/>` and then, later on, access myVar like so: `<s:property value="#myVar.thing"/>` to call `myVar.getThing()` or even `<s:property value="%{#myVar.getThing()}"/>`.

Comment: Not sure why this popped up today as a review from a new user.